# Subdomain won't serve javascript files, but direct ip address will

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04

http://projects.codemelody.com/OGS/themes/default/js/pdf.js/src/worker.js

This is my subdomain that points to a VPS that I own. If you follow the above link the webserver will say that it can't find that file. However, if you replace "projects.codemelody.com" with the ip address of the VPS it loads fine. And even if you just simply look at the /src/ folder using the subdomain you can see that all the files are in the directory.

```
Direct link via IP:
http://198.98.121.195/OGS/themes/default/js/pdf.js/src/worker.js
```

Files in src folder via Subdomain:
http://projects.codemelody.com/OGS/themes/default/js/pdf.js/src/

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: I've found an answer to my own question. In the original folder the name of the folder was "pdf.js" the period in the directory name causes Apache to not serve files that were under it. 

When I made a copy of "pdf.js" to a new folder "pdfjs" all files under pdfjs loaded correctly.

Comment: You should post your answer below. Self-answering is encouraged here.